# Which way is legal to store Youtbue API data

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

Im planning on making a website which stores user playlist data to share with other users in different way than youtube allow (My users will be able to view all records of all the playlists they created in a single list and etc) .

But I wonder if i can store data received from the Youtube API Data (playlist title, description, date, list of videos, thumbs addresses, etc) in my website database or the only way is to store in web server Session.

Of course I know that save of stream is not allowed.

---

Thank you very much, but I asked them if storing data generated by YouTube API Data (not JSON or XML results but data etc. title, description, id, thumbs addresses etc) in the database is consistent with the rules. The rule is the point:

Caching. Your API Client may employ session-based caching solely of YouTube API results, but You must use commercially reasonable efforts to cause Your API Client to update cached results upon any changes in video metadata. For example, if a video is removed from the YouTube service or made "private" by the video uploader, cached results shall be removed from Your cache. For the avoidance of doubt, Your API Client shall not be designed to cache YouTube audiovisual content.

What did they mean by a "session-based caching" and "YouTube API results".

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing in your database, then you can give additional fields that he one advantage, and allow the user to overwirite the title and description etc, if you don't want the user database  then rely on youtube data , these are preotyt XML,JSON data and very lightweight, it' good to implement to save the recenet snapshot in you database